# Execute php function in another part of code

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress based website.

I have a standard wordpress loop that executes at the start in the `<body>` part of the html. Now, i would like to print out the **og tags** in the head, but the data needed for those tags (title, description,...) is available to me after the `<head>` part when i do the loop.

Is there a way to solve this in php without me having to move my code to the beggining of the head tag (or somewhere before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is settiing meta tags, this works for me and is also useful because it checks if you are viewing a post or the website

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_author()) { ?>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_bloginfo('description')); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (function_exists('wp_get_attachment_thumb_url')) {echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); }?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a hook for [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action.

```
function modify_head()
{
  ?>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
  <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'modify_head');
```